# Passing specific login credentials to custom commands from fixtures

Tags: enumeration, cypress

I am attempting to utilize Cypress for various forms of testing, and have hit a snag with what I believe is syntax. I have generated a fixtures JSON file that contains two forms of ID under a name in the following format:

```
"USER": {
    "stationID": "(value)",
    "profileID": "(other value)"
  },
```

When calling the custom command for logging in, I pass in the accountname as "account" ("USER" in this case) along with and env variable from the cypress.config. I am attempting to retrieve the associated attributes of the named account from the fixture and pass them directly into two free form fields, like so...

```
Cypress.Commands.add('login', ({env, account}) => {
    cy.fixture('users').as('usersJson')
    cy.visit(Cypress.env(env))
    cy.get('#warning-modal-ok-btn').click()
    cy.get('.panel-footer > a').click()
    cy.get('#stationIdPopUp').type(account.stationID.usersJson)
    cy.get('#usernamePopUp').type(a hardcoded value)
    cy.get('#passwordPopUp').type(another hardcoded value)
    cy.get('#profileIdPopUp').type(account.profileID.userJson)
    cy.get(':nth-child(6) > .col-sm-12 > .loginBtn').click()
    cy.get('#center-header > h1').should('be.visible')
  })
```

The result is a set of undefined entries for the inputs to the stationID and profileID fields. Could someone kindly tell me where I am going off the rails?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

First thing I suspect is - `.type(account.stationID.usersJson)` doesn't seems to be right; as `usersJson` is an alias of fixture.

You can read more on the fixture usages here,

1. https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/fixture.html#Syntax
2. https://example.cypress.io/commands/files

There are plenty of approaches to fetch data from JSON and use it in the test.

1. Here is the approach with **Cypress fixtures**,

**File:** `cypress/fixtures/queriesData.json`

```
[
    {
        "sample": "SOME_DATA"
    },
    {
        "sample": "SOME_DATA_1"
    }
]
```

In my test, I'll consume the data like below,

```
cy.fixture('queriesData').as('queries')
cy.get('@queries').each((query) => {
    //Use the value of query here
    cy.log(query.sample) //Output: 'SOME_DATA'
})
```

2. Another approach with **importing the JSON file directly into test**,

**File:** `some_path/jsonFile.json`

```
"USER": {
    "stationID": "(value)",
    "profileID": "(other value)"
  }
```

Then in my test, I import the JSON file and consume the data,

```
import * as userData from "some_path/jsonFile.json"

cy.log(userData.USER.stationId) // Output: (value)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe your .type code should look like this:

```
cy.fixture('users').as('usersJson')
cy.get('#stationIdPopUp').type(usersJson.USER.stationID)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi i have also faced the same issue and I found a solution is that you just need to import your fixtures folder file in commands.js and after that, you can simply access your fixtures file as shown below:

```
//import you json file
import loginFile from '../fixtures/login.json'

//access the fixtures file by below command
cy.get('#stationIdPopUp').type(loginFile.USER.stationID)
```

The above solutions work for me and I hope that even works for you too.